# Artifactory-Pro docker upgrade: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey

Tags: artifactory

When upgrading our artifactory-pro environment (hosted on docker on AWS ECS Fargate), we're receiving a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey`.

Our current version is 7.68.14, and I'm trying to upgrade to [7.71.5](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-7.71.5-self-hosted).

We're using the docker images provided by jfrog out-of-the-box (no additional updates on our side):
`docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.68.14`
`docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.71.5`

Troubleshooting wise I've tried adding the `-verbose:class` option to the JVM:

```
[38.076s][info][class,load] java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec source: jrt:/java.base
[38.449s][info][class,load] java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey source: jrt:/java.base
[38.450s][info][class,load] sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateKeyImpl source: jrt:/java.base
[180.249s][info][class,load] org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey source: file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar
[1;33m[jfac ][0;39m [1;31m[ERROR][0;39m [66522bd28ad9dba1] [.s.b.w.s.s.ErrorPageFilter:184] [7.0.0.1-8040-exec-11] - Forwarding to error page from request [/api/v1/registry/join/router] due to exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey]
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey
```

It seems like the class is loaded correctly.

So not really sure what's going wrong here.
We're using an EFS volume that contains our configuration files and an RDS Postgresql database.

Any idea on how to continue from here?

Upgrade from version 7.68.14 to 7.71.5: `docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.68.14` to `docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.71.5`.

Expectation: Succesful upgrade (no breaking changes according to jfrog documentation).
Result: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateKey` .

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else runs into this issue: it was resolved by updating the trial license we'd been using for our non-prod environment to test the the upgrade.

The ClassLoading error was not relevant to the issue at hand.